# Класс ArrayList и вопросы по нему

Tags: java, коллекции

> Внутри каждого объекта типа ArrayList хранится обычный массив
>   элементов.

1. `transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access`

   Вот нашёл в классе `ArrayList`, это он? И почему написано: "Внутри каждого объекта типа `ArrayList` хранится обычный массив
   элементов, а не внутри класса?"
2. > Когда ты считываешь элементы из ArrayList, он считывает их из своего
   >   внутреннего массива. Когда записываешь – записывает их во внутренний
   >   массив.

   Как понять считывает? И я не очень понял что за внутренний массив.

Comment: Если бы этот массив был статическим, можно было бы говорить, что он хранится внутри класса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> И почему написано: Внутри каждого объекта типа ArrayList хранится
>   обычный массив элементов, а не внутри класса?

Потому что в самом классе лишь декларация. Сам массив объектов хранится в конкретном экземпляре класса - в объекте.

> Как понять считывает? И я не очень понял что за внутренний массив.

Считывание - это чтение элемента методом `get`. Внутренний массив - это тот самый `transient Object[] elementData;`.

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван поля класса, помеченные `transient`, при сериализации не будут сохраняться/восстанавливаться.